# java, eclipse "The import laobjects cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Using Eclipse Mars, I copied a tiny Java program from the Internet that displays a small window containing a "Click me!" JButton and a JLabel.  Every time you click the button, the label is updated to show the total number of clicks.  Trying to learn about Java packages, I added this package statement at the top:

```
package nineteen_3;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args {
    ...
    }
}
```

This code worked fine.

Learned the trick of making a JButton that looks like a JLabel, Decided to make a package of new objects beginning with KLabel, a modified JButton.

```
package laobjects;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class KLabel extends JButton {
    ...
}
```

No compile errors.

Back in Main {}, I added this import statement for `KLabel`. Below are existing import statements:

```
import laobjects.KLabel;
```

... and get: The import `laobjects` cannot be resolved

And in the Main {} code:

```
KLabel lbl = new KLabel("Count: 0");
```

I'm getting `KLabel cannot be resolved to a type`

Both the Package and Project Explorers show 'KLabel' as hi-level entries:

```
KLabel
  src
    laobjects
      KLabel.java
        KLabel
          label
          KLabel(String)
```

Comment: clean the project once... make sure u have enabled Build automatically .. if not.. build it manually

Comment: Are the `Main` class and the `KLabel` class in different _projects_? If so, your project containing the `Main` class must also declare a dependency to the other project. Better: Place the package and its classes into the `src` folder of the same project.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick replies!

Comment: Many thanks for your quick replies!  I did the clean and build to no avail.  Main and KLabel were in different projects, and Main didn't belong where it was.  So I created a ClickMe project and moved class Main to ClickMe.  Then to declare ClickMe's dependency on the KLabel project, in Eclipse I right-clicked the ClickMe project, chose Properties | Java Build Path, and added the KLabel project in the right-hand pane.  The red 'X's went away, and the code worked without further changes.  Thank you again!  I also investigated doing "an IDE import" and think that would have worked, too.